# How to do 1D interval clustering into clusters with equal number of intervals?

Tags: python, clustering

I am trying to analyse genomic data. They are organized in the form of records.

A record looks like the following:

```
record #    start end string
    1        xxx   xxx xxxxxx
    2        xxx   xxx xxxxxx
```

The records are arranged in a way that they are sorted based on the start column. I want to divide these records into multiple clusters because all of them dont fit into memory.

But genomic data of this kind has a feature ie records tend to cluster together (either overlap or occur "close" to each other).

So if I convert start and end columns into intervals it seems to me that they can be clustered together.

An idea for closesness if a super cluster's mean closer to a candidate interval.

The approach I've tried:

Merge all intervals to form disjoint super intervals. But this lead to some many super intervals with few points and only few with large number of points. But this approach will not constrain the clusters to have equal number of points in them.

An example for this:

```
[(3, 4), (6, 7), (9, 10), (1, 2), (3, 8)] - input intervals

[(1, 2, [3]), (3, 8, [0, 1, 4]), (9, 10, [2])] - super intervals with input interval's indices in the inner list.
```

Comment: This question needs more information to be answerable. Your problem is unclear because in general there won't be a unique way to merge the intervals and you don't provide any effective criterion for doing so.  For instance, one solution to your problem as stated is to keep all the intervals distinct: each such "super interval" contains the same number -- one -- of intervals.

Comment: I've added more information on what I've tried and ideas I had. Can kmeans work here?

Comment: I still can't discern enough information even to figure out what you are trying to accomplish.  Some of the questions you raise are (1) what does the sorting on the left endpoints have to do with it? (2) What is the purpose of the clustering? (3) How do you propose to assess whether one cluster is superior to another?  The basic problem is that you haven't provided any statistical context, which makes this just an incompletely specified math problem.  What do these intervals represent and what are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: I have tried my best to address all the points. I have also provided an example of the clustering.

Comment: Examples are good, but this example doesn't appear to solve your problem: you have collected three of the intervals into one and left the other two alone.  In what sense are there "equal numbers of points" in this result??  And in larger examples, where there will be a huge number of ways of combining intervals, how are we to determine which solutions are the ones you want? As far as the edit goes, could you explain what aspect of RAM limitations might be addressed by this question?  The connection is obscure.

Comment: By splitting intervals into equal sized bins I can send these records to worker nodes to do computation on them. So each cluster of records goes a worker node machine. The requirement for equal size is because I also want to make sure that I'm utilizing most of the RAM on worker machine.

The example I gave is for the approach I've tried, which doesn't have the equal cluster membership constraint.

Comment: In this context, *constraining* the clusters to equal size looks overly restrictive and leads to a hard problem.  Why not make it your objective to achieve the best possible *balance* among cluster sizes while specifying how many clusters you need (which presumably would be given by the number of available worker nodes)? Then, you might need to include among the objective some measure of how "homogeneous" each cluster is. For instance, if more-homogeneous clusters can be processed more efficiently, you accept more intervals within the more homogeneous clusters.